# Migration from Fedora to CentOS

Tags: centos, migration, upgrade, fedora

I did go through some articles about migrating to CentOS but not specifically from Fedora to CentOS. I'd like to know the steps and measures to follow

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried so far so we can reproduce your issue.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a migration path from CentOS to Fedora or vise versa. even though both systems share the same codebase   CentOS is way older than Fedora. I used to be a distro hopper way back, but I kept the /home directory in a different drive so I could install any distro I wanted and keep my data and configuration files intact. You should consider doing the same.